# Нужно спарсить все фото на сайте, но у меня получется только одну

Tags: python, парсер, requests, telebot, beautiful-soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import telebot




@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def parse(message):
    url = "https://wallpapers.com/" + message.text
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

    all_links = soup.find_all("a", class_="lozad")
    for link in all_links:
        url = link["href"]

    all_images = soup.find("li", class_="card content")

    img = all_images.findChildren("img")[0]
    img = "https://wallpapers.com/" + img["data-src"]

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"{img}")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)


Хочу спарсить все обои с сайта https://wallpapers.com/ при этом в телеграм бот пользователь должен написать что он хочет, к примеру bmw, и парсер должен отправлять все фото bmw из сайта, я это сделал, но он отправляет только одну.
```

Comment: У вас довольно странный цикл `for`, который просто перебирает ссылки. Зачем? Наверно в нем должен быть какой-то другой код. Так же `bot.send_message()` действительно отправляет только одно сообщение. Какого поведения вы от него ждете?

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://wallpapers.com/steampunk"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
all_links = soup.find_all('li',  class_="card content")
for link in all_links:
    print("https://wallpapers.com/" + link.img['data-src'])
```